# Thread synchronization in client-server like application?

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads, client-server

I have been working on a file download application, where server continiously waits new connection requests from clients, when a new connection arrives server accepts this connection and creates a new process to serve the client recently connected to server. Clients can request to download multiple files from server. For each file , client and server sides create a new thread and the data transfer for each file should be carried out between the proper thread couples of the server and client. I'm using C and **pthread** for threads. I have stable socket connection and successful process creation for each client for now.

For threaded file transer, i had an attempt as follows:

In client i'm creating threads which runs a method to receive files:

```
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < fNameCounter; k++)
        {
            pthread_t thread_id;
            int status = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &receiveFile, fName );

            if (status != 0)
            {
                printf("Thread Creation Failed \n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Similarly in server side, i create same number of threads as follows:

```
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < fnameCounter; k++)
        {
            pthread_t thread_id;
            int status = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &sendFile, fName );

            if (status != 0)
            {
                printf("Thread Creation Failed \n");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
```

sendFile and receiveFile functions simply writes and reads the bytes of files specified by fName(as you can see in pthread_create) by socket, at that point i have a major problem:

In this program as far as i  thought, there might be problems that files' contents may be different after the all threads complete receiving data from server, because since sendFile and readFile functions just reads from the socket and writes to the socket.

How can i guarantee that, each thread of client gets the proper data from the proper thread of server like i explained below:

```
        receive         send

cthread1 ---->  a.txt  <-----   sthread1

cthread1 ---->  a.txt  <-----   sthread1

cthread1 ---->  a.txt  <-----   sthread1
```

p.s.  i'm aware that creating many threads on one socket does not makes sense but, it is my hw and i need to do in that way :/.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to open a new socket for each file.

Answer (score 0):

To complete zvrba very valid point (one socket, one file).

I think the threads are useless here: you have one network card. You won't get faster by listening to the same resource several times. You're actually likely to have your threads block each other and be actually slower.

If you want to give feedback to the user, then you may create one background threads for all the socket IO.

You should handle your several connections in the same thread using `select` to detect which socket may be read from / written to.

Comment: well actually, it is a course project therefore i need to do in that way. Also, i'm aware that it is pointless to use threads since i will serve from one socket for each client   but i have no choice :)  and really stuck with that synch issue.

Comment: Please then edit your question to make your constraints clearer : send many files in parallel using a single socket and many threads on both side. Mention that this is an assignment and that the conditions, however in efficient are not negotiable.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the restriction of only one socket, you might want to add some header info to the bytes being transmitted. This header might contain information about which pair of threads is responsible for that bit of information.

For example, `sthread1` will send 100 bytes from file `a.txt`. You might add one byte to the beginning of that stream, containing the number `1`. When receiving that chunck of data, `cthread1` needs to check the first byte: if it is `1` then ok, this chunk is for `cthread1`, proceed processing. If the header isn't `1`, then `cthread1` should *ignore* this chunk and keep waiting, giving the other threads opportunity to run too.

If you don't identify your chunks of data, it will be impossible to determine which thread should process which chunk.

Please note that this adds a lot of complexity to deal with:

1. You will have to decide how to assign those identifiers to your pairs of threads
2. If you use only one byte, keep in mind that the maximum value it holds is 255.
3. You might have to use the flag `MSG_PEEK` in your `recv` function inside `cthread` (so you can ignore the chunk if needed). This flag alters the behaviour of the function `recv`. I advise you to read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (if you're programming on Win) or [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/recv.html) (if you're on Linux).